# grub not showing ubuntu even after boot repair

Tags: grub2

I had installed windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 side by side using dual boot.

Recently I reinstalled my windows and the grub menu disappeared .I ran a boot repair from my ubuntu live cd to reinstall grub but it is still not showing ubuntu but only windows in grub   *

<sup>* pastebin link is no longer valid</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Install EasyBCD software on windows
>   2.Create a boot entry for your ubuntu partition
>   
> 3.After Restart select ubuntu from the grub
>   
> 4.You will be get back into Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the root cause of the problem is that you have a separate /boot/ partition which was at one point properly configured in your /etc/fstab but you (or some other person/script) commented out the fstab entry for this /boot/ partition. This can be seen by this line in your /etc/fstab from sda9:
`#UUID=3a7e4da4-1e7c-4c01-9b8b-b2a7248c62f5 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2`

I don't know why this is commented out, but it appears to be a mistake. This caused your grub.cfg not to contain any entries for Ubuntu because update-grub creates an entry for each kernel found in /boot/, since your /boot/ partition wasn't mounted you didn't *have* any kernels in /boot/ and thus no Ubuntu entries were made.

To fix this from a LiveCD/USB, first mount the partition containing your Ubuntu installation's root filesytem: `sudo mount /dev/sda9 /mnt/` then edit your fstab: `gksudo gedit /mnt/etc/fstab`. That last command should open your fstab in gedit, find the line
`#UUID=3a7e4da4-1e7c-4c01-9b8b-b2a7248c62f5 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2`

and uncomment it (remove the '#' character from the beginning of the line) then save your changes and exit gedit.

With your fstab fixed, you can now re-install grub and you should get options for both Ubuntu and Windows at boot. Using boot repair to re-install grub will probably work, but I would personally recommend following this guide instead:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#ChRoot

Answer (score 0):

Run Boot-Repair, **update it**, click `Recommended Repair`. Done.